# Typescript strictNullChecks and closures

Tags: typescript, closures, typescript2.0

Let's say I have code like this:

```
function f(x: string | undefined) {
    if (x) {
        console.log(x);
        Promise.resolve()
            .then(() => g(x))  // error, x is string | undefined
    }

    // x = undefined;
}

function g(y: string) {
}
```

The `if (x)` acts as a type guard, so `x` has type `string` at the `console.log`. But when referenced from the closure in the `.then`, its type is `string | undefined`. This must be because the value could change back to undefined outside the type guard, before the code in `.then` runs. But if it doesn't get set again, Typescript must not be doing the kind of analysis that would let it detect that.

I can work around it by using the `!` operator on `x`. But I find that I do this sort of thing often in my codebase, and it doesn't protect against being broken later by making x undefined.

Is there any other way around this? Am I understanding the problem correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you can do either one of these:

(1) Use const:

```
function f(x: string | undefined) {
    if (x) {
        const x2 = x;
        Promise.resolve().then(() => g(x2));
    } else {
        // x = undefined;
    }
}
```

(2) Call `g()` before the promise:

```
function f(x: string | undefined) {
    if (x) {
        let y = g(x);
        Promise.resolve().then(() => y);
    } else {
        // x = undefined;
    }
}
```

Comment: 1 - Good point, in fact it's not that you have a const reference, it's that you have a new reference which is only type `string`. So `let` and `var` work too. Would lead to some clutter though.
2 - True, but I usually can't do that in the scenarios I'm thinking of. Otherwise I already would :)

Comment: Yeah, I guess you're right about the const part, I started trying to put it in the function's param, but that's not allowed so I copied it to the body of the function without changing it to var/let.